# How to count how many times the user has typed the wrong answer (Python)

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python, soo, yeah.
Basically i have this:

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.10)

name=input("What's your name?")
question1=input("How many centimeters are one meter?")
if question1=="100":
print("Correct!")
question2=input("How many meters in a centimeter?")
if question2=="0.001": 
    print("Correct!") 
import os 
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls') 
time.sleep(1)
delay_print("Calculating results...")
time.sleep(3)
print("Good job,", name, "!")
```

and i am asking questions: to be precise 2.
So i want to keep track of how many times the user has got a question wrong so at the end i can display how many questions were right, and how many wrong.
Then i want to show a specific message:
For when all of them are right, the one that i have already typed.
For when one is right and one wrong i want to type:
"Not bad (name), but be more careful!"
And last but not least, when he/she gets it all wrong:
"Oh man! That is very bad (name)! Be more careful!"

Comment: Have some variable `number_correct = 0` and then add one to it `number_correct += 1` every time you print `correct`

Comment: use `else` and a counter variable?

Comment: how many meters in a centimeter is not == 0.001

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHaugh but i need a way to make python look at the number and tell if it's 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @Philipp I dont care if its right or wrong, just making a test program so i can learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply add `else` statements to your `if` statements to handle what your program should do if the answer is wrong and if it is wrong count it.Lastly make a `print` statement depending on the number of mistakes user did using another `if` statement:

```
import time
import sys
import os

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.00)
    print('\n')    #new line for keeping it neat

count = 0#variable to store num of wrong answers
name=input("What's your name?")
question1=input("How many centimeters are one meter?")
if question1=="100":
    print("Correct!")
else:#if its wrong do this
    print("wrong!")
    count = count + 1#adds 1 if wrong
question2=input("How many meters in a centimeter?")
if question2=="0.001":
    print("Correct!")
else:#if its wrong do this
    print("wrong!")
    count = count + 1#adds 1 if wrong

time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')
time.sleep(1)
delay_print("Calculating results...")
time.sleep(3)
if count == 0 : #if nothings wrong do this
    print("Good job,",name,"!")
elif count == 1:# if 1 one wrong do this
    print("Not bad,",name,",but be more careful!")
else:#else if everythings wrong do this
    print("Oh man! That is very bad,",name,",be more careful!")
```

Output:

```
What's your name?Food
How many centimeters are one meter?67
wrong!
How many meters in a centimeter?00.01
wrong!
Calculating results...

Oh man! That is very bad, Food ,be more careful!
```